# Why is there a parse error?

Tags: haskell, syntax

Why is there a parse error on this? I insert a list and want to get tuples out. (The top line is correct).

```
freq :: Eq a => [a] -> [(Int,a)]
freq x:xs  = [(x,y)| (x,y) x <- count , y <- rmdups]
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two syntax errors here — no parenthesis on the pattern, and wrongly placed `(x,y)` inside the comprehension. It should be:

```
freq (x : xs) = [(x, y) | x <- count, y <- rmdups]
```

Comment: It says that freq lacks an accompanying binding... do you know what this could mean?

Comment: @user1351008: That means that you've given the type of `freq`, but not the definition.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put parenthesis in your pattern match

```
freq (x:xs) = {- ... -}
```